# Buddypress get data from wp_bp_groups_members table

Tags: buddypress

I have added a new column to 'wp_bp_groups_members' table it's called 'relationship'. Now I want to get data from that column. I have to pass user_id and group_id to get that data.

Comment: Can you please add a little more explanation to the question and also explain what are you planning to accomplish in here. Also add the working code along with the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already find a way. I'll post it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler solution:

```
function get_relationship($group_id,$user_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $relationships = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT relationship FROM wp_bp_groups_members WHERE group_id = $group_id AND user_id = $user_id");
    if ( !empty( $relationships ) ) {
        foreach ( $relationships as $relationship ) {
            return $relationship;
        }
    }
}
```

And it should go in plugins/bp-custom.php or your-theme/functions.php.
Not bp-groups-template.php, which is a core file and should not be hacked.

Comment: Hmm, could you explain in what way is your solution different from Sassis answer? Your code is exactly the same (if you ignore variable names).

Comment: Exactly?  get_col != get_results.  I check for empty. I show that you don't need to use '.' in the select. I correct his typo re $id in the select.  And I point out that he doesn't need to hack a core file.  Ok?

Comment: It's exactly the same solution. You've just added minor corrections. You could just add your comments to Sassis answer and not add another one which is almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new function in bp-groups-template.php file.

```
function get_relationship($group_id,$user_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $groups = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `relationship` FROM `wp_bp_groups_members` WHERE group_id=". $id ." AND user_id=".$user_id);
    if ( $groups ) {
        foreach ( $groups as $group ) {
            return $group->relationship;
        }
    }
}
```